# How can I align the left edge of HTML form elements using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to do the following:

```
aa:   ________
bbbb: ________
ccc:  ________
```

So I wrote:

```
<span>aa:</span><input type="text" /><br/>
<span>bbbb:</span><input type="text" /><br/>
<span>cc:</span><input type="text" />
```

And I get:

```
aa:________
bbbb:________
ccc:________
```

I know I can arrange it easy with table. How do I do it without tables with as few css as I can.

Thanks.

Comment: Just curious, what’s wrong with using a table in this case?

Comment: Probably because, like my grandpa says, "That's not how we do". But +1 anyway because you're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<style>
    label {
        float: left;
        clear: left;
        width: 3em;
        padding-right: .5em;
    }
</style>

<label for="a">aa:</label> <input id="a" type="text" /><br/>
<label for="b">bbbb:</label> <input id="b" type="text" /><br/>
<label for="c">ccc:</label> <input id="c" type="text" />
```

Comment: what is the difference between label and span? what is for?

Comment: Just for the record @Naor, you _could_ do the same thing with your `<span>` tags, but using `<label>` would be the more semantically appropriate way to go.

Comment: This alignment breaks if the label text is wider than 3em, for example with 'bbbbbbbbbb:'.

Comment: @Naor: `<label>` is for labelling form elements (whereas `<span>` doesn’t have any meaning). The `for` attribute indicates which element is being labelled. In most browsers, when you click on the `<label>`, its `<input>` will be focused. It also helps screen readers.

Comment: @Saul: yeah, this solution is a bit content-dependent. Although if you make the labels reasonably wide, then for realistic labels, the label will just wrap onto two lines.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to float the `span` to left and the `input` to right, while wrapped into a `div`:

```
<style type="text/css">
 span.left { float: left; clear: left; }
 input.right { float: right; clear: right; }
 div.container { width: 333px; }
</style>

<div class="container">
 <div><span class="left">aa:</span><input type="text" class="right" /></div>
 <div><span class="left">bbbb:</span><input type="text" class="right" /></div>
 <div><span class="left">ccc:</span><input type="text" class="right" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace each `<span>` with `<span class='fixedwidth'>` and use this css rule:

```
.fixedwidth, input{
  display:block;
  float:left;
  clear:left;
  width:100px;
}
```

Comment: and what if the "aaa" will be more then 100px?

Comment: @Naor increase the value to 200px. If it's still too small increase it to 300px. Keep going until it fits. You might want to stop around 1600px though.

Comment: I think you should set some reasonable width. Am not aware of any way to align the columns across the rows dynamically without using javascript.

Comment: but I don't know the size of the labels. It depends on th user.

Comment: @Naor: sure, but there aren’t many words in English that are longer than, say, 12 letters. If you want all the labels to be as wide as the widest label, you need to use a `<table>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this(tested in FF):

CSS:

```
.label
{
    width: 75px; /*Or any width you want*/
    display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<span class="label">aa:</span><input type="text" /><br/> 
<span class="label">bbbb:</span><input type="text" /><br/> 
<span class="label">cc:</span><input type="text" />
```

Comment: and what if the "aaa" will be more then 75px?

Answer (score 0):

Use some sets of divs with float and clear attributes.